# Spring Social Twitter - API changes, url callback

Tags: spring, spring-social

There were some changes in Twitter API recently, as a result using Twitter with Spring Social is no longer possible. Twitter say that callback_url parameter must be provided from now on. Apparently Spring doesn't handle it because loging as twitter user is no longer possible. Any ideas?

https://twittercommunity.com/t/action-required-sign-in-with-twitter-users-must-whitelist-callback-urls/105342